# Unable to install the Force.com plugin for eclipse. getting md5 mismatch

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com

I'm trying to install the Force.com IDE plugin. I found it, it started downloading, but once the plugin goes to install I get the following error at about 45% completion:

`Installing software has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed`

When I click details about this error, I get the following. Anyone know how to fix this and get the plugin installed? Thanks in advance

`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.salesforce.ide.api,23.0.2.201201091635.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 97a6329f82c422a61e9b1bc28be7cace and found ef8b1c2b63c7d04acaa6bf41f4b8570c.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution: download plugin jar files manually and put them into eclipse installation directory. The problem was in corrupted (partial) download of jars by eclipse.

1. Download all jars of particular needed version from http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/features/ and http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/plugins/
   Make sure to use some download manager to ensure files integrity!
2. Then put them to /features/ and /plugins/ folders of your eclipse installation directory accordingly.
3. Run plugin installation as described by salesforce (Jars will not be downloaded again) - Success!

Comment: After manually downloading the jars, do I just place them in the root of the features and plugin class? I do this and then follow Salesforce installation guide and it still just says pending forever.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running Eclipse as an Administrator (right click, select "Run as Administrator") when installing plugins.

If that doesn't help, move your Eclipse folder to the C:\ on Windows because there are issues with the Program Files folder permissions. Then run it as an Administrator and try to install the plugin again.

Comment: I have the same problem, and neither solution worked. Also worth noting that if you download the free one from the force.com site the Zip file is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working;

- Install Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios SR1)

  - [The IDE FAQ recommends Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_FAQ#What_Eclipse_versions_are_compatible_with_the_Force.com_IDE.3F), but [the install instructions link you to 3.6 SR1](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.6) .
- Ensure you only have the latest JRE

  - I am running Java 6 Update 26 as of this post.
- Make sure you don't have any legacy JREs installed

  - I had to uninstall a 1.4 Java environment before the IDE install would work.
- Then follow what Matthew Keefe said;

  - Run Eclipse *As Administrator*
  - Move the Eclipse program directory outside of the `Program Files` directory.

**Edit**: Eclipse 3.7 installs the IDE successfully once the Java version is correct.

Comment: Well my eclipse is in  D folder only. Tried running as administrator but no help. Its really frustrating downloaded all versions of eclipse but i was getting the same error everywhere.

Comment: Did you determine your Java version? The change for me was fixing Java. Turned out the IDE version isn't as important.

Comment: Well i have  java 1.6.0_25. Should I upgrade this? Since it was not working for higher version i downgraded it to 1.6.0_25

Comment: Make sure its **all** you have. My problem was that Eclipse was finding a 1.4 JRE that I had forgotten about.

Comment: ya i checked that.Actually I formatted my system and and I also checked that I have only this version. Still I am getting the same error.